# using fitdistplus package in R

Tags: r

my question i want to fit data with censored to my model with 4 parameters

my codes :

```
 library(fitdistrplus)
d11<-data.frame(left=c(72,411,228,126,118,10,82,110,314,100,42,8,144,25,11,30,38,4,54,13,123,97,15,59,117,16,151,22,56,2,18,139,20,31,52,287,18,51,122,27,54,7,63,392,10,8,92,35,117,132,1,16
                       ,3,95,177,162,216,553,278,12,260,200,156,182,143,105,103,250,100,999,112,87,231,242,991,111,1,587,389,33,25,357,467,201,1,30,44,283,15,25,103,21,13,87,2,20,7,24,99,8,99,25,95,80,51
                       ,29,24,18,83,31,51,90,52,73,8,36,48,7,140,186,84,19,45,80,52,164,19,53,15,43,340,133,111
                       ,231,378,49),
                right=c(72,411,228,126,118,10,82,110,314,NA,42,8,144,NA,11,30,38,4,54,13,NA,NA,15,59,117,16,151,22,56,2,18,139,20,31,52,287,18,51,122,27,54,7,63,392,10,8,92,35,117,132,1,16
                        ,3,95,177,162,216,553,278,12,260,200,156,NA,143,105,103,250,100,999,112,NA,NA,242,991,111,1,587,389,33,25,357,467,201,1,30,44,283,15,25,NA,21,13,87,2,20,7,24,99,8,99,25,95,80,51
                        ,29,24,18,NA,31,51,90,52,73,8,36,48,7,140,186,84,19,45,80,52,164,19,53,15,43,340,133,111
 ,231,378,49))

#pdf of my model 
dw<-function(x,a,b,c,d) {2*a*b*(c^2)*d*x*exp(-(x*c)^2)*(1-exp(-(c*x)^2))^((d*b)-1)/(1-(1-exp(-(c*x)^2))^(d))^(b+1)*exp(-a*(1-exp(-(c*x)^2))^(d*b)/((1-(1-exp(-(c*x)^2))^(d))^(b)))}

##cdf of my model 
pw<-function(q,a,b,c,d) {


  (1-exp(-a*(1-exp(-(c*q)^2))^(d*b)/((1-(1-exp(-(c*q)^2))^(d))^(b))))}


model3<fitdistcens(d11,"w",start=list(a=0.02,b=0.02,c=0.0002,d=0.0002),optim.method="Nelder-Mead")
summary(model3)
```

my problem with this step

model3

i got error said :

```
Error in fitdistcens(d11, "w", start = list(a = 0.02, b = 0.02, c = 2e-04,  : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
        with the error code 100
```

Comment: In my experience `Error code 100` is due to convergence problem. Are you sure that the `dw` and `pw` functions have been correctly specified ?

Comment: Yes i am sure of pdf and cdf this problem  happen with me alot even i use simple pdf also happen

Comment: I search on google what i understand is that i have to choose suitable intial values to run the codes as not any intial values could Run the codes. In one simple pdf when i choose situble intial values it is run when change intial values i got same problem here.any help choose suitable intial values of this model

Comment: Your help is higly appriciated

Comment: Any one could help please .how to choose suitable intial values